# Calling the most recent PFObject

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I have a timer that counts down the current date to a date I set in Parse (classname: "Date"). Right now, it retrieves that data using an ObjectId that I've set. I'd like to set it to call the most recently updated object in the class, using date in the "updatedAt" column. How can I do this?

```
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //      Retrieve the date in Parse

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Date")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("CSJFqvJDqs") {
            (dateFromParse: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && dateFromParse != nil {
                // Process everything here

                // Step 1: Get the current date.
                let currentDate = NSDate()

                // Step 2: Convert the dateFromParse PFObject into a NSDate object
                let electionDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
                electionDateComponents.day = dateFromParse!["Day"] as! Int
                electionDateComponents.month = dateFromParse!["Month"] as! Int
                electionDateComponents.year = dateFromParse!["Year"] as! Int
                let electionDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(electionDateComponents)!

                // Step 3: Find the difference between dateFromParse and currentDate
                let timeToElection = electionDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(currentDate)
                let daysToElection = (((timeToElection/60)/60)/24)
                print(daysToElection)

                //              Step 4: Display the number of days of difference on countDown.text
                let daysText =  String(format: "%.0f days", floor(daysToElection))
                self.countDown.text = daysText
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should browse through the SDK documentation and guide:

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries

Queries have sort methods. You want to do something along the lines of

```
[query sortDescending:@"updatedAt"];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *dateObject, NSError *error)
{
    //do your stuff
}];
```

Sorry, just realized I gave you obj-c syntax and you're using swift. I'm not familiar with swift, but the methods should be the same. Just have to call them Swift style.

Comment: It was close to this! I posted my solution. Thanks for help!

Comment: No problem. While I didn't write the code for you, I did provide you the answer to your question. You asked how to get the most recently updated object using the updatedAt key. My answer should be marked as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! First I had to create the election date in Parse "electionDate". I then had to create the currentDate constant so I could use it as reference for "greaterThanOrEqualTo".

```
let date = NSDate()
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let currentDate = cal.startOfDayForDate(date)

    let query = PFQuery(className:"Date")
    query.whereKey("electionDate", greaterThanOrEqualTo: currentDate)
    query.orderByAscending("electionDate")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
```